# bulk insert sqlalchemy core with on conflict update

Tags: sqlalchemy, upsert, on-duplicate-key

I want to insert multiple items into a table and upsert the table on conflict. This is what I came up with the following

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
meta = MetaData()
jobs_table = Table('jobs', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
stmt = insert(jobs_table).values(jobs)
stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
    index_elements=['j_id'],
    set_= dict(active=True)
)
result = engine.execute(stmt)
return result.is_insert
```

The `j_id` is a unique field and I am trying to update the row if it already exists. I get the following error if the row already exists.

```
(psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "j_id"
DETAIL:  Key (j_id)=(0ea445da-bd1d-5571-9906-0694fa85728a) already exists.
```

Is there something that I am missing here ?

Answer (score 2):

`stmt.on_conflict_do_update` returns a new statement. If you change to the following it should work:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
meta = MetaData()
jobs_table = Table('jobs', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
stmt = insert(jobs_table).values(jobs)
stmt = stmt.on_conflict_do_update(index_elements=['j_id'],
                                  set_= dict(active=True))
result = engine.execute(stmt)
return result.is_insert
```

You can `print(stmt)` the statements to see the resulting SQL query. This can be useful to see if the statement which you are going to execute has the expected expression. Also adding `echo=True` to `create_engine` can be helpful to detect issues!